# error when passing array into a method

Tags: java, arrays, object, parameter-passing

when I run the code:

```
Reading z = new Reading();
Resident[] resident = new Resident[hotel.getKambariuSkaicius()];
z.readFile(Resident[] resident); // Error in this line
```

I get an error: 
'.class' expected, 
';' expected, 
unexpected type 
required: value 
found: class

I don't understand what is wrong passing 'Resident[] resident'. Maybe someone can help?

Comment: do `z.readFile(resident)`

Comment: delete this: Resident[]  from the method call.

Comment: `z.readFile(resident);`

Comment: In `z.readFile(Resident[] resident);` , what purpose does `Resident[]` serve?  What Java syntax are you following?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Just pass the variable like following

```
z.readFile(resident);
```

Just pass it as other variable. In Java, Arrays are passed by reference.